# Bidirectional pair matching using cost function

Tags: python, optimization, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization

I have a square cost function matrix A with equal width and height that has for all elements A[i][j] = A[j][i].

These represent the cost of traveling from node i to node j. How can I find the lowest cost to establish links between pairs of nodes, keeping that each link is either bidirectional (there is a link from i -> j and j-> i) or links back to itself, considered a link for these purposes, as i would equal j in this case. Each node therefore has a maximum of 1 incoming/outgoing node.

I've tried using the Hungarian Algorithm to solve the linear assignment problem, but this leads to loops where each link is not bidirectional. I have started writing a genetic algorithm, but I feel like there should be another optimization algorithm or method to solve this more efficiently.
If there is not, is there a good Python library to solve this problem quickly?

I am trying to match people based on a cost function. I aim to have groups of 2, and cannot have groups > 2.

Comment: In the title you say you want to do pair matching... then why would there be "links back to itself"? Is that also considered a "pair"?

Comment: @trincot In short yes that would be considered a pair for these purposes; the thought is to deprioritize "links back to itself" via making the cost greater, but "links back to itself" are allowed.

Comment: From your explanation it sounds like you're doing a variation of The Traveling Salesmen problem. There is an implementation in [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.traveling_salesman.traveling_salesman_problem.html), but generally speaking depending on the formulation of your problem and specific constraints, defining your own objective function in a package like [Gekko](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) may result in a significantly faster solution.